# Leaflet routing machine get route summary without drawind route

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

I am using LRM to calculate routes. And I need data about this routes. Now I'm just learning how to exctract this data so I can use it further. 
I have two routes

```
var routing1 =  L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: [
                L.latLng(54.736038, 55.97429),
                L.latLng(54.736985, 55.980878),
            ],
        });

var routing2 =  L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: [
                L.latLng(54.732798, 55.969934),
                L.latLng(54.734954, 55.95809)
            ],
        });
```

I have a button to draw this routes

```
document.getElementById("drawing").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
        function myFunction() {
            routing1.addTo(map).on('routesfound', function (e) {
                distance = e.routes[0].summary.totalDistance;
                console.log('routing1 ' + distance);
            });
            routing2.addTo(map).on('routesfound', function (e) {
                distance = e.routes[0].summary.totalDistance;
                console.log('routing2 ' + distance);
            });
        }
```

As I don't quite understand JS yet so I have this question:

---

How can I console.log route's summary the moment route calculated? Without drawing it.

Comment: For some reason `routing1.on('routesfound', function (e){}` doesn't work (and I think it should but maybe I'm missing something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TomazicM** helped me with solution:

---

Upon investigation it turns out that quite a big part of routing process depends on adding L.Routing.control to map. To force route calculation and prevent showing of route on the map requires some hacking trickery:

Itinerary display must be prevented with show: false option.
Endpoints marker display must be prevented by dummy marker creation option `createMarker: function(p1,p2) {}.`
Internal _updateLines method has to be replaced with dummy method.
Routing control must be added to map with onAdd(map) method.

Final code then looks something like this:

```
var wayPoint1 = L.latLng(57.74, 11.94);
var wayPoint2 = L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949);

var bounds = L.latLngBounds(wayPoint1, wayPoint2); 

var myRouting = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [wayPoint1, wayPoint2],
    routeWhileDragging: true,
    show: false,
    createMarker: function(p1,p2) {}
});

myRouting.on('routesfound', function (e) {
    distance = e.routes[0].summary.totalDistance;
    console.log('routing distance: ' + distance);
});

// save original mathed for later use
var _updateLines = myRouting._updateLines;

myRouting._updateLines = function (p1) { };

map.fitBounds(bounds);
myRouting.onAdd(map);
```